# How to install Tor hardened using terminal

Tags: kubuntu, tor, tor-browser

I'm using Kubuntu 16.10 and I'd like to install tor browser bundle. I saw that there is a tor hardened version and sandboxed version.
I downloaded packages but just extracting them doesn't work for me. So I need now to know how can i install both of them using terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ["Linux Instructions"](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads-hardened) section in the download page.

Take the hardened version for example, just decompress the file: `tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-6.5a6-hardened_ALL.tar.xz`

And change the working directory: `cd tor-browser/`

Start the browser: `./start-tor-browser.desktop`

One note on the instruction page is that **not to unpack or run TBB as root.**